# Is there a away for the spilt method to split depending on what the user has entered in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, split, mapping

```
user_lst = list(map(int,input("Numbers: ").split(" ")))
```

So that line just maps the list to the corresponding `int` values, but is there a way for the `split` method to detect whether it is splitting on a , or " " or any other character?

For example, if the user enters

> 1,2,3,4

or

> 1 2 3 4

or

> 1-2-3-4

I want it to split the list by the specified split character.

I tried this:

```
user_lst = list(map(int,input("Numbers: ").split(" ","-",",")))
```

but obviously `split` only takes two arguments at most. But even with only two arguments it still gives that error.

I know you can use a few `if` statements and indexing to first check what the user has used to separate it with, but I just want it done on one line or two at most.

Comment: The version of `.split()` from the `re` module can accept an arbitrary pattern to split on - for example `[- ,]` would match any of the three characters you mentioned.

Comment: When the user inputs, for example, `1,2,3,4`, what is the rule that tells you that `,` is the split character? Why shouldn't the split character instead be, for example, `3`, leading to the result `('1,2,', ',4')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the regex `split` function instead of the base `.split` method:

```
import re

PATTERN = r"[-, ]"

user_lst = list(map(int, re.split(PATTERN, input("Numbers: "))))
```

You can change `PATTERN` to any regex pattern which will match the symbols you want to be able to split on. More on regex patterns [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) and you can play around with your own patterns on [regex101](https://regex101.com/)